# Installing GitLab on Ubuntu: "Could not resolve host: packages.gitlab.com"

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab

This is my system (fresh install):

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

I've already installed OpenSSH and Postfix and added the GitLab repository, but when I try installing GitLab, this is what I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gitlab-ce
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 743 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,961 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 gitlab-ce amd64 12.8.1-ce.0
  Could not resolve host: packages.gitlab.com
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/pool/xenial/main/g/gitlab-ce/gitlab-ce_12.8.1-ce.0_amd64.deb  Could not resolve host: packages.gitlab.com

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried both recommendations and even tried changing networks, hoping it was the school Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 0):

Try and access first https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce in a browser.

If that fails as well, it might be the case the domain is blocked by a firewall.